# Jenkins Test reports for specific flavors -Android

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have three product flavors paid, free, market in my application. I have one folder androidTest with same kind of tests for three flavors.Test reports are being generated for different flavors with same package androidTest/com.app.tests.

I'm using jenkin's to display the test reports for each flavors using "**/androidTest-results/**/*.xml", but the problem here is all the tests of flavors comes under "com.app.tests" package. I want to differentiate the test results for different flavors in jenkin's graph report with package name . Any help can be appreciated.